# StackTrace shows xxxxx is causing the crash. But "specialized closure #1" means what?

Tags: swift, core-data, stack-trace, crash-reports, ios11

Please explain the below crash..

> #3. NSManagedObjectContext 0x1701c9ab0: xxxxxxxxxx
> 0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1848898e8 __ulock_wait + 8
> 1  libdispatch.dylib              0x18475977c _dispatch_ulock_wait + 48
> 2  libdispatch.dylib              0x1847598a4 _dispatch_thread_event_wait_slow + 36
> 3  libdispatch.dylib              0x1847574f0 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 236
> 4  CoreData                       0x187c0703c _perform + 232
> 5  CoreData                       0x187c178b8 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 176
> 6  CoreData                       0x187b675e0 -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 580
> 7  MyApp                     0x1002f596c specialized static RecentItemsController.cleanupItems(inContext:ofType:limitingTo:sortingByAttribute:withPredicate:)
> (xxxxx.swift:182)
> 8  MyApp                     0x1002f6574 specialized closure #1 in static xxx.xxx(inStore:completion:) (xxx.swift:163)
> 9  MyApp                     0x1002f5118 partial apply for closure #1 in static xxx.xxx(inStore:completion:) (xxx.swift)
> 10 CoreData                       0x187c0c214 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 152
> 11 libdispatch.dylib              0x1847469a0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
> 12 libdispatch.dylib              0x184754ad4 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 928
> 13 libdispatch.dylib              0x18474a2cc _dispatch_queue_invoke + 884
> 14 libdispatch.dylib              0x184754fa8 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 344
> 15 libdispatch.dylib              0x184756a50 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 540
> 16 libdispatch.dylib              0x1847567d0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 124
> 17 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18494f100 _pthread_wqthread + 1096
> 18 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18494ecac start_wqthread + 4

Comment: If you look toward the end of those lines you'll see `RecentItemsController.swift:182`. That's where the crash happened, in that file at line 182. That's the code you need to look at.

Comment: Why not line number 163?

Comment: It says that the code on line 163 called the code on line 182. Line 163 may be involved but line 182 is where the crash happened.

Comment: How to interpret that line number 163 called line number 182 & not the vice versa?

Comment: Because that's how stack trace ordering works. Also if you look at those two lines you can probably tell which one calls the other.

Comment: Edited the question to show line number 163 & 182.

Comment: But what can be the cause of the crash ?

Comment: As preventive fix I enclosed the 
"itemsToDelete.forEach(context.delete(_:))" inside a check whether itemsTodelete count is greater than 0.
            if itemsToDelete.count > 0 {
                itemsToDelete.forEach(context.delete(_:))
                log("Deleted \(itemsToDelete.count) \(type) item(s)")
            }

Comment: The crash is somehow related to pvt. context.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the stack trace and the code inside `cleanupItems` func, I believe the problem is in the force unwrapping code:

```
let itemsToDelete = try context.fetch(request) as! [R]
```

The first thing to write a crash preventive code is below

```
if let itemsToDelete = try context.fetch(request) as? [R] {
   itemsToDelete.forEach(context.delete(_:))
   log("Deleted \(itemsToDelete.count) \(type) item(s)")

}
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Thank You for the answer Sir, but it is not the cause of the crash. What I know is completion handler getting called twice & that is causing the crash & the crash is related to multiple context of core data.

if let completion = completion {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: completion)
                }

Comment: CoreData is not thread safe. If you think `cleanupAllRecentItems` is called multiple times at the same time and causing the crash, you may perform this function as a block on a serial queue instead.

Comment: Its not the "cleanupAllRecentItems", "completionHandler" is called twice & causing the crash.

Comment: And if I want to implement your suggestion for completion handler, will it be enough, if we call completion handler as sync to the main queue? : "if let completion = completion {
     DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute: completion)
    } "